# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '[object Array]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an object, who has an array in its props. I am trying to change an item's value inside this array (inside the object). This object is coming from Redux.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState(useSelector(selectProducts).find((item) => item.id === id))
console.log(product)
//  { name: "",
//    imageUrls: ["https://blabla","https://blabla2","","",""],
//    quantity: "" }
```

I can set any prop of product object with setProduct method **without any problem**, also the array as a whole can be updated with setState. I mean I can use those without problem:

```
setProduct({...product, name: "BOOK"})
```

or

```
setProduct({...product, imageUrls: ["SHIT", "GLASS"]})
```

But I cannot set the state of a single imageUrl' value which is inside imageUrls array. The error written in the title comes.
I tried

```
 setProduct((prevState) => {
  let copy = {...prevState}
  copy.imageUrls[i] = ""
  return copy
 })
```

And then the error comes: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '1' of object '[object Array]'`
I also tried adding

```
Object.defineProperties(product, {imageUrls: {configurable: true, writable: true}})
```

Then, again error, `object is not redefinable.`

I think I am having this problem not because of the logic is wrong, it is just because I could not use the correct syntax. Can you help?

Comment: `copy.imageUrls[i] = ""` - should this be `copy.urls[i] = ""` according to your `console.log`?

Comment: it is about spelling mistakes in question, sorry, I edited now

Comment: what you need to change in object?

Comment: could you please show us the full code?

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade now I edited, the setState method initial state is coming from redux, the whole code is very long but the brief explanation of error is that I wrote in question

Comment: Also the value in redux is assigned from firebase getDoc in another component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think of your `setProduct` method as a way of updating `product` in a "non-mutational" manner. Hopefully, that will lead to passing values to the function that achieve what you're after. So, you're already doing this for non-array items (e.g. `setProduct({...product, name: "BOOK"})`). The same can also be done for altering indexed items within the array item, with code similar to the following:

```
setProduct({
  ...product,
  imageUrls: product.imageUrls.map((item, index) =>
    index === 2 ? "newValue" : item
  ),
});
```

Where the above changes the value of the second index item in the imageUrls array.
One of the problems in your sample code is that you're using `i` but it doesn't appear to be defined. If `i` is defined in the context where `setProduct` is being called, then the above sample code could be altered so that the `2` is replaced with `i`

Comment: Yes Shiraz, your solution is correct. The [i] var is defined in mapping function, therefore problem is not about it. But the correct syntax is the one that you wrote. Thanks bro!

Comment: @JeremyFc, I realise I didn't answer your question directly, but wanted you to see the problem from a different angle.  It's worth getting used to "non-mutational" methods on the Array object to make it easier when using the "set" method related to `useState`.  I would also consider changing your data structure so that you don't use an Array if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const selectProducts  = [
{name:"",imageUrls:["https://blabla","https://blabla2","","",""], quantity:""},
{name:"",imageUrls:["https://blabla3","https://blabla4","","",""], quantity:""}
]
const persistedProducts = selectProducts.map((product)=>{
  const {imageUrls, ...productWithoutImageUrls } = product;
 
  
  return {
    ...productWithoutImageUrls,
    imageUrls: imageUrls.map((imageUrl)=>"")
  }
})

console.log(persistedProducts)
```

Comment: Can you look again the question? I edited the first line of the code part. Your method of destructuring the urls is a new idea, I will try it tomorrow and write feedback here.

Comment: This works when you write by hand, but it doesn't work when the selectProducts comes from Redux. Can you look at the question? The single product object is acquired from Redux. The problem is I can set all of its props with setProduct but I cannot set imageUrls prop only.

Comment: Also, I can set imageUrls array to something as a whole, with this code: setProduct({ ...product, imageUrls: ["SHIT"] }) but I cannot set value of single item in the array

Comment: I'm sorry I thought that redux was an backend integration, but it's a state manager for react, right? 

Just I thought, could your try changing  ```javascript const [product, setProduct] = useState(useSelector(selectProducts).find((item) => item.id === id))``` for ```javascript 
const {product, setProduct} = useState(useSelector(selectProducts).find((item) => item.id === id))```

Comment: Then it violates the rule of useState hook I think. Now I tried, it gives error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try with this?

```
const productState = useSelector(selectProducts);
const [product, setProduct] = useState({ ...productState });
```

Then you can use setProduct wherever you want to update product.

Comment: Now tried this, doesn't change, same error comes